# Is this a DDD rule?

Tags: c#, linq, domain-driven-design

Ok so I have a database-table with **1000 rows**.

**From these I need to randomly extract 4 entries.** 
This is a business rule. I could easily do the random thing in LINQ or SQL. But my Domain project must be independent, not referencing any other project.

So I should have a list there, load it with all the 1000 rows and randomly extract 4 to be DDD-clean.

Is this ok? What if the db-table has 100k rows?

Comment: Are the primary keys sequential?

Comment: The ids could be 1,2,5,7... (ascending order, but some of them missing). Not sequential :) But I get where you're going, I could create a new column where I would ensure a sequential order and only pass the video count.

Comment: Just pick four random numbers, that are within the row-count, then select the rows with those [`ROW_NUMBERs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) from the SQL Server.

Comment: thanks EBrown! Seems legit!

Comment: @Proka It's not the *most approved* of practice, but that value is guaranteed to be the relative number of each row (probably as it is stored on disk). The AS/400 (System i) we have at work uses `RRN` (relative record number) instead, but the principle is the same. Our `RRN` is indicated as the data is stored physically.

Comment: Just encapsulate this logic in a repository and write it in SQL. `entriesRepository.randomEntries(4)`. Repositories exists to shield your domain from persistence concerns, use it at your advantage.

Answer (score 0):

If the primary keys were sequential and not interrupted then that would yield large performance benefits for the 100k or beyond tables. Even if they are not sequential I believe you can just check for that and iterate lightly to find it.

Basically you are going to want to get a count of the table

```
var rowCount = db.DbSet<TableName>().Count(); //EF for pseudo
```

And then get 4 random numbers in that range

```
var rand = new Random();
var randIds = Enumerable.Range(0,4).Select(i => rand.Next(0,rowCount).Array();
```

And then iterate through that getting the records by id (this could also be done using a contains and the id, I was not sure which was faster but with only 4 find should execute quickly).

```
var randomRecords = new List<TableName>();
foreach(int id in randIds)
{
    var match = db.DbSet<TableName>().Find(id);
    //if the id is not present, then you can iterate a little to find it
    //or provide a custom column for the exact record as you indicate in comments
    while(match != null)
    {
        match = db.DbSet<TableName>().Find(++id);
    }
    randomRecords.Add(match);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Travis's code, this should work for you.  It basically gets a count of records, generates 4 random numbers, then asks for the nth record in the table and adds it to the result list.

```
var rowCount = db.TableName.Count();
var rand = new Random();
var randIds = Enumerable.Range(0,4).Select(i => rand.Next(0,rowCount));

var randomRecords = new List<TableName>();
foreach(int id in randIds)
{
    var match = db.TableName
      .OrderBy(x=>x.id) // Order by the primary key -- I assumed id
      .Skip(id).First();
    randomRecords.Add(match);
}
```

You could also do something like this, *IF* you have an autoincrementing id field that is the primary key.  The caveat is this isn't a fixed time function since you aren't sure how many loops may be required:

```
var idMax = db.TableName.Max(t=>t.id);
var rand = new Random();
var randomRecords = new List<TableName>();
while(randomRecords.Count()<4)
{
   var match = db.TableName.Find(rand.Next(0,idMax));
   if(match!=null)
     randomRecords.Add(match);
}
```

If you don't care for absolute randomness (This is very very not random, with some things weighted more than others), but this is the fastest method, requiring only one database trip:

```
var idMax = db.TableName.Max(t=>t.id);
var rand = new Random();
var randIds = Enumerable.Range(0,4).Select(i => rand.Next(1,idMax));
var query=db.TableName.Where(t=>false);

foreach(int id in randIds)
{
   query=query.Concat(db.TableName.OrderBy(t=>t.id).Where(t=>t.id>=id).Take(1));   
}
var randomRecords=query.ToList();
```

Comment: One thing to consider here is that `Skip` can be a very expensive call to make in large tables.

Comment: @TravisJ Not if you are ordering by the primary key.

Comment: I wasn't aware that it made that optimization.

Comment: @TravisJ I'll double check, but since the primary key is always indexed, it would just have to traverse the index.  Maybe if it was an absolutely huge table with billions of rows, but then just about anything would be slow.  But I'll check to make sure.

Comment: @TravisJ Apparently not quite as optimized as I had hoped.  In my quick tests, asking for the 6 millionth record in a 6.x million row table took 1.6 seconds, 600kth took 0.22 seconds, and the 2nd took 0.008 seconds.  So it is not instantaneous.  It is doing an index traversal, but traversing that many records still takes time.

Comment: Updated answer with solutions that work better in different scenarios.  The second and third should work better with very large tables.  The second prefers better randomness, the third prefers speed.